# How to check if a particular line in a text file starts with a particular word(s)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a text file into which I write the paths to all files in a disk partition.

```
WriteToFile::WriteToFile(QString path, QString data)
{
    path = "E:/Data.txt";
    QFile file(path);
    if ( file.open(QFile::Append) )
    {
        data += "\r\n";
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << data << endl;
        qDebug() << "Writting: " << data;

    }
}
```

I only write new paths into the file.

```
void ScanDir::qDirIteratorScanner()
{
    // QString basePath;
    QDirIterator it(this -> basePath, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        // QStringList paths;
        paths = scanned();
        QString path = it.next();

        qDebug() << "Collected : " << paths.size();

        if (!paths.contains(path)) {
            WriteToFile writeToFile(basePath, path);
            paths << path;
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "Already put : " << path;
        }
    }

}
```

I anticipate that I will sometimes start scanning a partition, but stop the program before it finishes scanning a partition. I would like to mark where I last stopped by appending "LAST-SCAN-POINT" to the start of the last path entry into the file *(if it was a new path)*, or last `if (!paths.contains(path))` *(if I terminated the program while it was checking if the path had already been inserted into the file)*

How can I check a text file for a line starting with **LAST-SCAN-POINT**

**Data.txt**

> C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7010.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7011.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7012.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7013.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7014.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7015.idrc
>   **LAST-SCAN-POINT** C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC 2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7016.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7017.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7018.idrc
>   C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC
>   2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7019.idrc

Answer (score 1):

How about using `QString::startsWith` [method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#startsWith)? Like for example:

```
QString path = "LAST-SCAN-POINT C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe InDesign CC 2015/Plug-Ins/Layout/(Alignment Panel Resources)/idrc_PNGA/7016.idrc";

if(path.startsWith("LAST-SCAN-POINT ")) {

    qDebug() << "The path starts with 'LAST-SCAN-POINT '";
} else {
    qDebug() << "The path does not start with 'LAST-SCAN-POINT '!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simply searching the txt file for "LAST-SCAN-POINT" you can do something like this:

```
int readFile(std::string path)
{
std::ifstream filestream(path);
std::string line;
char lsp[16];
int i = 0;
while (std::getline(filestream, line))
{
    std::stringstream linestream;
    linestream << line;
    linestream.get(lsp, 16);
    if (std::string(lsp) == "LAST-SCAN-POINT")
    {
        filestream.close();
        return i;
    }
    i++;
}
filestream.close();
return -1;
}
```

This will return the line LAST-SCAN-POINT is on or -1 if it does not exist.

Comment: Note that Qt offers a more appropriate solution, though yours should work. Maybe also note that your stream is not closed if you found the line.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for catching that. Didn't see that I left that line out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ***readLine*** function of QFile (docs here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readLine) to read one line at time and then use the function ***startsWith*** of QString as illustrated by Moe Abdul-Hameed